# Find the ratio of the perimeter of a square and of a triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle, ratio

**Problem:**

Let the square $ABCD$ be on the side $l$ and the points $E$ and $F$ on the sides $BC$ and $CD$ respectively so that $\angle EAF= 45$. Find the ratio between the perimeter of the square and the perimeter of the triangle.

**The drawing:**

[image]

**My idea:**

First of all we can simply say that the perimeter of the square is $4l$

I noted $\angle DAF=x$ and $\angle EAB=y$.

As you can see in the drawing $\angle DFA=y+45$ and $\angle AEB=x+45$.(1)

We can simply show that $\angle PEA= \angle AFM= 45$(2)

From (1) and (2) we can say that $\angle PEC= y+45$ and $\angle MFC= x+45$

I thought of showing some congruences(I think that angles of trinagle are $45,75,30$ which means we can a right angles isoscel triangle and a $30,60,90$ triangle back to back). I also thought of taking the midpoint of $FE$ and applying the median theorem corresponding to the hypotenuse.

I don't know what to do forward! Hope one fo you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: You must be missing some additional Criteria , otherwise , the Perimeter will vary with $x$ & there is no Constant Answer. Over-all , Answer will be between 0.75 (minimum) & 0.85 (maximum) , not Constant !

Comment: @Prem I looked again at the source of the problem. There are no missing pieces of information.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the problem is incomplete. If this is homework, I'd suggest finding the perimeter ratio when your angle $x$ is $0$ and when it's, say, $22.5^\circ$, to show you get different answers. If you're just doing work yourself, try making $x$ a parameter, so that the ratio is a function of $x$.

Comment: We can take Square Side=1 , then let $x=0$ , to get $y=45$ , then we will get Perimeter $P=1+1+\sqrt{2}$ & Perimeter ratio is $0.8535534$ (maximum) , then we let $x=22.5=y$ & use basic trigonometry to get $P=1.08239+1.08239+0.8284=3$ & Perimeter ratio is $0.75$ (minimum) , then we can try with other values of $x$ to get other Perimeter ratio values !

Comment: @IonelaBuciu: As other commenters have mentioned, the problem appears incomplete. The perimeter of the triangle varies according to the position of $E$ (and $F$). So, what kind of solution do you want? An expression of the perimeter ratio based on some parameter? (Which one?) The minimum ratio? Something else? ... Be sure to describe what you want in the body of the question. (Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Comment: @Blue Can we take $l$ (the side of a square) as a constant?

Comment: @IonelaBuciu: *"Can we take $l$ (the side of a square) as a constant?"* ... Since the question asks for the ratio of perimeters, the actual length of the side of the square is irrelevant. Varying the position of $E$ along $BC$ still changes the (relative) perimeter of the triangle.

Comment: @IonelaBuciu: What is the source of this question? Is it some kind of online challenge whose details may have gotten lost in being re-re-re-shared over social media?

Comment: @Blue Actually is in one of my math books.

Comment: @Blue What constants can we take then? (also thank you for trying to help)

Comment: @IonelaBuciu: *"What constants can we take then?"* ... It's impossible to glean the author's intent from the information given, so it's difficult to suggest what additional assumptions to make without over-complicating the problem. Maybe $E$ is the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$. Or maybe just define $x:=|BE|$ and calculate the perimeter in terms of $x$. Or maybe something else. ... I wonder if the textbook diagram might have visual clues that don't appear in your version; can you post a photo of the page? ... "Extended discussion" warning. I won't be replying again. Good luck!

Comment: In internet forums using ALLCAPS is the equivalent of yelling. Please, don't yell at us.

Comment: I too see the "Extended discussion" warning & will not comment again , @Blue , but I want to highlight my earlier Points which might have been overlooked : (1) I have already said Question is missing Details (2) Perimeter ratio is dependant on Position or angle (3) Perimeter ratio is independent of Side length $l$ which can be taken arbitrarily (4) Question has unique Solution when it is changed to get minimum value of the Perimeter ratio , which is 0.75 with trigonometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Comment:

As can be seen in figure the altitude of triangle is always equal to $l$. If we suppose triangle is symmetric about diagonal AC of square , then we have:

$\angle EAB=\angle FAC=22.5^o$

$AE=AF=\frac l{\cos 22.5}$

$EF=2GE=2 AE \sin 22.5=2l \tan 22.5$

$P_{\triangle}=\frac{2l}{\cos 22.5}+2l\tan 22.5$

$\frac {P_\triangle}{P_\square}=\frac{\sin 22.5+1}{\cos 22.5}\approx 0.7494$

As can be seen the ratio is not constant, for example with triangle AHI we have:

$\frac {P_\triangle}{P_\square}=\frac{6.91+6.22+5.06=18.19}{4\times 6}\approx 0.7579$